# Redirecting CoCreateInstance to fake implementation

Tags: c++, winapi, com

Given some existing code which calls `CoCreateInstance` to create instances of registered COM objects, is there a way to redirect these calls to create a different instance instead?

The idea is that within the same process (for testing purposes), and without altering the original code or affecting any other processes, when it asks for the system-provided `CLSID_ShellLink` (for example) it would create an instance of a custom type (implemented in the same codebase) that implements the same interface, not the "real" instance that it would normally create.

For clarification: I'm looking for an API call that can be made to say "hey `CoCreateInstance`, call this local thing to create an instance first before going to look at the registrations".  And it does have to be something that can be done programmatically, not by manipulating the registry or a config file; it needs to be toggleable within the code.

Comment: Not sure if this would work or not but if registration free COM overrides registered information then you could create a manifest that tells COM to create your proxy instead of the standard object. I simply don't know if COM looks in the AppCtx first or last.

Comment: I've done this using `CoRegisterClassObject`, as xMRi suggested. AFAIK, that's the "Right Way™" that you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed like the sort of thing that COM would implement internally, since it has lookup tables and remote computer hooks and all sorts of other weird and wonderful things.  It's basically just a different kind of object factory.

At least for the moment, though, I've just used an API interceptor to hook `CoCreateInstance` itself and redirect it to a custom function.  It works.

I'll leave this open for a while longer yet in case anyone does know the Right Way™ to do this within COM itself.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this in COM. You can implement this easily in your own program though. Don't call CoCreateInstance directly. Call your own function that forwards to CoCreateInstance. And in that function you can map the class IDs.

Comment: That's what I'd normally do, but in this case the actual call to `CoCreateInstance` is buried a few layers down, and inside a third-party library.

Answer (score 2):

If the objects you are creating are in process and if you can call CoRegisterClassObject in the process you are talking of, you can register your own class factory for the specifiv object... depends also from the flags used when CoCreateInstance is called.

Comment: Yes, but I think "create in process" is not sufficient. One would need to `CoRegisterClassObject` in the same apartment and in this case it would have a priority above standard dispatching through COM registration.

Comment: I'm not sure that there's an issue here. OP stated that they want to be able to set this up from within the process that calls `CoCreateInstance`. They may well be able to do it from within the same apartment.

Comment: I'm a little fuzzy on the apartment distinction, but I can say that at least one call passes `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER`, which normally requests out-of-process creation, but I want to ignore that in this case.  Although I might be able to change this to request `CLSCTX_SERVER` instead, which I think allows in-process use too.

Comment: What makes me nervous about this is that it still appears to be globally registering the class.  Again, what I'm trying to do here is to _temporarily_ replace a **standard system class** (such as `CLSID_ShellLink`) for requests made by my own process.  I absolutely do not want any other process to be affected by this while the "redirection" is active.

Answer (score 1):

> I'll leave this open for a while longer yet in case anyone does know the Right Way™ to do this within COM itself.

One of the methods is mentioned [by xMRi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56442932/868014) above and is especially useful when you need to redefine instantiation within scope.

Another true COM method is to engage a "treat as" emulation. [CoTreatAsClass function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/objbase/nf-objbase-cotreatasclass) on MSDN features the API itself, and Remarks section gives a good description.

When enabled, requests to `CoCreateInstance` on given `CLSID` will be redirected to new emulation `CLSID`.

Comment: That's the sort of thing that I was looking for, but it's still making a global registry change to do it, which is a much bigger brush than I want.

Comment: Correct, it's global but relatively safe change. One thing to try as well (which I never tried unlike the mentioned two) is to register a per-user CLSID which overrides global COM server. Most of the registrations are global and if per-user CLSID registration have a priority in a collision, then fake object would be picked up for current user and the change does not need administrative privileges to get enabled (a more complicated variant: to duplicated original registration per user and then duplicate TreatAs on a user's copy).

Answer (score 0):

Since COM creation is based on CLSID registration, you can overwrite the known CLSID with your own proxy class. This however is not supported and might lead to undefined behaviour. Also, it would depend on the way CoCreateInstance is called (the CLSCTX enumeration).

Comment: No, I specifically don't want to do that.

Comment: Then how do you want to proxy the call? COM does not support subclassing like a HWND.